# NetBeans 8 - FTP server refused connection - Could not parse response code

Tags: ubuntu, sftp, netbeans, vsftpd

I try to connect to my server via sftp but I get `FTP server XY refused connection.`

So I tried it again with the FTP Client FileZilla, and there it works.

This is my config:

I also tried to change the port in NetBeans to 22 which is the port used for sftp... but then I get:

> "Cannot connect to server XY. (Cause: Could not parse response code.
>   Server reply: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH-7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8)"

[image]

**/etc/vsftpd.conf**

```
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
nopriv_user=ftpsecure
ftpd_banner=Willkommen auf dem Entwicklungsserver
ls_recurse_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
local_umask=002
chmod_enable=YES
file_open_mode=0644
anonymous_enable=NO
anon_world_readable_only=YES
syslog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
ascii_upload_enable=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
listen=YES
#listen_ipv6=YES

ssl_enable=NO
rsa_cert_file=
dsa_cert_file=
#
# Limit passive ports to this range to assis firewalling
pasv_min_port=30000
pasv_max_port=30100
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do not confuse FTP/FTPS with SFTP – they are completely different protocols.

- vsftpd is an FTP/FTPS server *only.*
- OpenSSH, WinSSHd are SFTP servers *only*.
- The `sftp` command is an SFTP client only.
- FileZilla is both an FTP/FTPS client and an SFTP client.

If you used an `sftp://...` URL in FileZilla, that's SFTP and you probably cannot connect to it via NetBeans directly, as it only supports FTP/FTPS.

Comment: But why does it work in FileZilla and not in NetBeans?

Comment: Because FileZilla does both SFTP and FTPS. What config do you use in FileZilla?

Comment: I did not setup any config, everything is in default. I just connect with `sftp://<<ip>>`

Comment: Right, so you're telling FileZilla to use SFTP, but you're telling NetBeans to use FTP. Those are different things.

Comment: Then how can I tell NetBeans to use SFTP?

Comment: Look under the "Encryption:" dropdown. If it has SFTP, select it. If it doesn't, that means you cannot use SFTP in NetBeans. (Try [this plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginDetailPage.jsp?pluginid=13195).)

Comment: Thats wrong, I can change the port to 22, which is the port used for sftp... but then I get another error: "Cannot connect to server XY. (Cause: Could not parse response code. Server reply: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH-7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8)

Comment: You're just changing the port number – that doesn't magically teach NetBeans to speak the protocol. That's what the error is saying: NetBeans doesn't understand what the SSH/SFTP server is sending, because NetBeans is expecting the server to be FTP, not SFTP.

Comment: I have other servers which I am connecting to via sftp successfully, so NetBeans does understand sftp. It even added the tag [SFTP] to the connection name.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding a new connection which gave me the option to select FTP or SFTP.

[image]

Now after selecting SFTP and configuring the connection again, it works.